# Qt how to zoom in a QWidget and its children

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpainter

I have a QWidget which has 2 child QWidget, I want to zoom in it (with its children) by 200% just like we zoom in an image. (as shown in screenshot below)

I know how to zoom in a single QWidget in its paintEvent() via QPainter. But I don't know how to zoom in a QWidget with children.

[image: screenshot]:

Comment: It looks rather like resizing than zooming.

Comment: Use QtQuick, if your GUI need such zooming

Comment: I cannot use QtQuick since this is a legacy project with new requirement. It's a Qt Designer like app.